# Unit testing models - advice

Tags: c#, oop, unit-testing

I have a project that multiple people work on. I have been building unit tests for our project.  (I know these should have been there from day 1 but I joined after the project was started.)

We have lots of models, with lots of properties. I was wondering if you would advise that I create unit tests to test these models are instantiated correctly and that the properties are set?

Comment: I would only test the properties whose getters/setters contain custom logic. For trivial properties (ex: `{ get; set; }`) I see no use in unit testing them.

Comment: Not sure if you are talking about testing the properties themselves ([This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593879/unittesting-properties-in-net) link has lots of great answers) or if you mean testing the properties values after instantiation.  Either way, you should test them.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you should concentrate on logic but not on data. This means that you should not test **state**, you should test **behavior** instead.

It is possible to have some behavior behind your properties. For example, changing state of one property should affect some other property's value (but in this case we still will test behavior and not state).

Every unit test should tell a story about class under test (c). Too many useless unit tests can hide relevant or important information about your system and actually reduce maintainability instead of increasing it.

Be pragmatic and add tests to most important parts of your system and cover most complicated business logic first and them move towards other parts of your system.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't test that they get loaded correctly for the ORM framework. I would however add tests if they have some logic in them, e.g.:

```
private IList<User> _allUsers;

public IEnumerable<User> GetActiveUser
{
   get { return _allUsers.Where(u => u.IsActive);
}
```

This might need some tests to ensure that you are only getting Active users.

Answer (score 1):

Test that the models are correctly persisted by whatever framework or data access layer you are using, as well as any business logic built into the models themselves.

I like to use NUnit + Fluent Assertions to compare a model before and after a persistence action (such as creating and saving a model, and making sure it retrieves with all values properly).

Note that it doesn't have to strictly be persistence. Perhaps your model is a view model, and is mapped from a business entity by a mapper. I'd test that, too. Basically, you want to test that a model transitions through some layer or logic correctly, not test the model itself (aside from any business logic built into it, of course). Testing language or framework features/that the compiler is working, as would be the case to test that properties work, seems to me to be a waste of time.

Crude example:

```
  // arrange
  var expected = new PersonModel
                  {
                     FirstName = "John",
                     LastName = "Doe",
                     DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now
                     // etc
                   }

   // act
   var id = InsertModelAndReturnId(expected);
   var actual = RetrieveModelById(id);

   // assert
   actual.ShouldHave().AllProperties().EqualTo(expected); // ShouldHave is from Fluent Assertions. This line makes sure expected and actual have the same values after being persisted and retrieved
```